# Teamcity: Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to run git at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe

Tags: git, windows-8, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

When I run my build it fails with the error:

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to run git at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

The path is correct, I can run the file and Teamcity is using my login account.

Is there somewhere I need to set more credentials, or start the service with Admin privileges?

I am running in Windows 8.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `git.exe` instead of `sh.exe`?

Comment: That's it!  Thanks.  If you want to add it below, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is correct, but TeamCity wants to execute `git.exe`, not `sh.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error to this.

The fix was to explicitly set the `Path to Git` in the VCS root to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe` - ie: Exactly what @John-Hoerr suggests.

The value prior was an empty string.

The reason for the failure was not clear since the `VCS Root` was used in a template which was being used by other builds completely fine. Possibly something to do with a detached, reattached template that I had done.